# How to reset password for Flureon HD IP Cam

Tags: reset, credentials, ip-camera

I lost my credentials to access my HD IP camera (in my particular case FLOUREON 1080P 10X/18X/30X ZOOM PTZ Dome Outdoor IP Camera, Model BT-HD54F). How can I recover my credentials or reset to default credentials?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for several days and trying to reset the credentials to default `admin:admin`, I got in contact with support and they provided me with a tool to reset the password:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QXmQsGNFUbpuwWCaOVMgcHow60Y3x556/view?usp=sharing

Inside you find `IPWizardIII_2.2.5`, start it and search for the camera. If found, click `Get` under `Verification Code` in the lower left corner of the form. Copy the code, open the `Code Authorization Tool`, paste the code and click the button. You receive another code, paste it in the `IPWizard_III`'s form and click `Clear Passwords`. Voilà!

Only drawback: it does not work on Windows 10, at least for me. I made it work on a Windows 7 virtual machine, though