# How to reset password of FLOUREON 1080P 18X ZOOM PTZ Dome Outdoor IP Camera, Model BT-HD54F

Tags: passwords, webcam

Someone accessed my webcam from outside, and changed the administrator password.
I have subtly blocked external access from my router, but now I need to reset the administrator password.

My HD IP camera  FLOUREON 1080P 10X/18X/30X ZOOM PTZ Dome Outdoor IP Camera, Model BT-HD54F.

I need to reset my administrator password
I found an answer from [bash.d](https://superuser.com/questions/1448015/how-to-reset-password-for-flureon-hd-ip-cam), for a similar problem, but the link he posted to fix it doesn't work.
I wonder if anyone has the tools to reset the password (Code Authorization Tool).

Otherwise I will be forced to throw away an excellent IP Cam...

[This is pictures of my cam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRoNc.jpg)

[This is pictures of my cam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3fi1.jpg)

[This is pictures of my cam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnyvD.jpg)

Comment: Does its manual not have a procedure to do fsctory reset

Comment: It's a very old camera, and I no longer have the manual

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem,
I used the Android app **Onvier - IP Camera Monitor** (PRO version) which saw the camera via Onvif and allowed me to reset the camera (connected via LAN) to factory settings, **and it worked !!!**
**Now the password is reset and I was able to log in and reset a new password**